# Django model serialization only returns primary key for foreign key

Tags: python, json, django

I'm trying to serialize my model to JSON to be passed to a JavaScript function. When I serialize the model it returns everything fine except for the foreign keys. They return the numeric primary key in the JSON.

**models.py**

```
class NameManager(models.Manager):
    def get_by_natural_key(self,
                           first_name,
                           middle_name,
                           last_name):
        return self.get(
            first_name=first_name,
            middle_name=middle_name,
            last_name=last_name)


class Name(models.Model):
    """Name model - contains properties for Name"""
    objects = NameManager()

    first_name = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    middle_name = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    last_name = models.CharField(max_length=200)

    def natural_key(self):
        return(self.first_name,
               self.middle_name,
               self.last_name,)

    class Meta:
        unique_together = ((
            'first_name',
            'middle_name',
            'last_name'),)


class SponsorManager(models.Manager):
    def get_by_natural_key(self,
                           sponsor_name,
                           sponsor_email,
                           sponsor_phone,
                           sponsor_address):
        return self.get(
            sponsor_name=sponsor_name,
            sponsor_email=sponsor_email,
            sponsor_phone=sponsor_phone,
            sponsor_address=sponsor_address)


class Sponsor(models.Model):
    """Sponser model - contains properties for Sponsor"""
    objects = SponsorManager()

    sponsor_name = models.ForeignKey(Name)
    sponsor_email = models.EmailField(default='Please enter')
    sponsor_phone = models.IntegerField(default=0000000)
    sponsor_address = models.ForeignKey(Address)

    def natural_key(self):
        return(self.sponsor_name,
               self.sponsor_email,
               self.sponsor_phone,
               self.sponsor_address)


class Show(models.Model):
    """Show model - contains properties for Shows"""
    BOX_CHOICES = (
        ('box', 'BOX'),
        ('gred', 'GRED'),
        ('boxgred', 'BOX/GRED'))
    show_date = models.DateField()
    show_time = models.TimeField(default=datetime.now())
    show_type = models.CharField(
        choices=BOX_CHOICES,
        default='box',
        max_length=8)
    show_box_total = models.IntegerField(default=0)
    show_address = models.ForeignKey(
        Address,
        related_name='show_address')
    show_sponsor = models.ForeignKey(
        Sponsor,
        default=1,
        related_name='show_sponser')
```

**views.py**

```
def dashboard_view(request):
    """render the admin view"""
    get_all_shows = Show.objects.all().order_by('show_date')
    json_shows = serializers.serialize('json', get_all_shows)
    print (json_shows)
    context = {
        'json_shows': json_shows
    }

    return render(
        request,
        'website/dashboard_view.html',
        context)
```

As you can see I've tried using natural keys, but with the same results. I could be approaching this all wrong to begin with and advice in a more correct approach would be great.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
json_shows = serializers.serialize('json', get_all_shows, use_natural_foreign_keys=True)
```

As stated in the [documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/topics/serialization/#serialization-of-natural-keys), you will need to specify `use_natural_foreign_keys=True` while serializing.

> When `use_natural_foreign_keys=True` is specified, Django will use the `natural_key()` method to serialize any foreign key reference to objects of the type that defines the method.

Comment: I swear I've been to that documentation twenty times and yet I've missed that everytime.

Comment: As it stands there is a foreign key inside a foreign key. This seems to be causing it not to serialize into JSON. Should I be doing it this way or another way altogether?